# react-native unexpected token on less-than symbol

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having an error on a very simple react-native app.

```
   15 |render () {
   16 |     return (
 > 17 |       <NavigatorIOS
      |       ^
   18 |         style={styles.container}
   19 |         initialRoute={{
   20 |           title: 'Sample',
```

No matter what I return here, it fails.

react version: ^15.1.0
react-native version: ^0.31.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `React.createClass({‌​...})` use `render: function() {}` but if you are using ES6 syntax `class Component extends React.Component` you can use `render() { ... }`

Comment: Yes, I'm using ES6, that's why I don't understand why the code is not working.
I think it might be related to a incompatibility issue between react and react-native, but I can't figure out.