# React give mistake before less-than symbol

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, babeljs

I have question like this one:
[react-native unexpected token on less-than symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38985135/react-native-unexpected-token-on-less-than-symbol/40092425#40092425)

Here all my stuff:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hi, my name is Cir. I am 19 and from Kiev, Ukraine. How are you ?</h1>  
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>React ToDos App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

webapck.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src'
    ],
    output: {
           path: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
           filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loader: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loaders: ["react-hot-loader/webpack", "babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015"]
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

My files tree

[image: My files tree]

Here is mistake. It happend before less-than sympol in my index.js

[image: Here is mistake]

I am still new in React, so sorry for my future stupid questions.

Comment: Do you have react loaders?

Comment: Whats <FirstRender/> ?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited it in <App/>.

Comment: Yeah. I ve added code of my webpack.config.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using babel presets so first make sure that you have installed `babel-preset-loader` using

```
npm install babel-preset-loader
```

Also install `babel-core` with `npm install babel-core`

Then in your webpack you need to edit the loaders as

```
loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react']
      }
]
```

Note that its `loaders` and not `loader` in module.

If this doesn't work then you can you can try another solution i.e. create and `.babelrc` file and then add the following to it

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

and omit the presets from the `webpack.config.js` file

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the lines to

```
import App from "./components/app";
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

---

If you try to use `components/app`, Node thinks that you want to use `app.js` script from `components` module. You can see modules in `node_modules` directory.

Where as `./components/app` means that you want to use `app.js` in `components` directory.

Also, you need to use `<App />` instead of `<FirstRender />`, because you are exporting `App` class, not `FirstRender`.

Comment: I have edited everything, but it still give the same mistake.